# Jquery function is not working with select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following select form and function to select the transport type first and I would like to have a list of cars or motorcycles in the second form depending on my choice at the first stage. I will really appreciate if you can let me know why my function is not working and what I am missing

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="transport" name="transport">
<option value="choose">Please choose a type</option>
<option value="cars">Cars</option>
<option value="motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
</select>
<select id="model" name="model">
<option>Please choose a type first</option>
</select>

<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</body>

<script>
(function(){
    var type = document.getElementById('transport');
    var model = document.getElementById('model');
    var cars = {
        Alfa_Romeo: '4 C Spider',
        Aston_Martin: 'V12 Vantage',
        Audi: 'A4 Allroad',
        Ford: 'Focus'
    };
    var motorcycles = {
        Yamaha: 'YZF-R6',
        Kawasaki: 'Versys 650 LT',
        Suzuki: 'Boulevard C50',
        Honda: 'Super Cub C100'
    };

    addEvent(type, 'change', function() {
        if (this.value  === 'choose'){
            model.innerHTML = '<option>Please choose a type first</option>';
            return;                                                                   
         }
        var models = getModels(this.value);

        var options = '<option>Please choose a model</option>';
        for (var key in models){
            options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + models[key] + '</option>'; 
        }                                                                             
        model.innerHTML = options;
    });

    function getModels(transport) {
        if (transport === 'cars') {
            return cars;
        } else if (transport === 'motorcycles'){
            return motorcycles;                                                                                      
        }                                                                    
    }       
}());
</script>
```

`

Comment: What is `addEvent()`?  Where is that function defined?

Comment: Also no mention of errors thrown in browser console

Comment: @David, thank you soo soo much David. addEvent is not working. It should be replaced with $("#transport"). change(function() {
    if (this.value  === 'choose'){
    model.innerHTML = '<option>Please choose a type first</option>';
    return;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Check this working snippet

```js
(function(){
var type = document.getElementById('transport');
var model = document.getElementById('model');
var cars = {
Alfa_Romeo: '4 C Spider',
Aston_Martin: 'V12 Vantage',
Audi: 'A4 Allroad',
Ford: 'Focus'
};
var motorcycles = {
Yamaha: 'YZF-R6',
Kawasaki: 'Versys 650 LT',
Suzuki: 'Boulevard C50',
Honda: 'Super Cub C100'
};

type.addEventListener('change', function() {
if (this.value  === 'choose'){
model.innerHTML = '<option>Please choose a type first</option>';
return;                                                                   
}
var models = getModels(this.value);

var options = '<option>Please choose a model</option>';
for (var key in models){
options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + models[key] + '</option>'; 
}                                                                             
model.innerHTML = options;
});
function getModels(transport) {
if (transport === 'cars')
{
return cars;
}
else if (transport === 'motorcycles'){
return motorcycles;                                                                                      
}                                                                    
}       
}());
```

```html
<select id="transport" name="transport">
<option value="choose">Please choose a type</option>
<option value="cars">Cars</option>
<option value="motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
</select>
<select id="model" name="model">
<option>Please choose a type first</option>
</select>

<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
```